# G HUB script keep running in an endless loop even after i release mouse button 8

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

the program seems to not detect when I release mouse button 8 and keep running in an endless loop.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8 then
      repeat
         PressMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(math.random(15, 45)) 
         ReleaseMouseButton(1) 
         Sleep(math.random(15, 45)) 
      until event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 8
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`event` is a local variable that doesn't change inside the function, so your loop that runs until it changes will run forever. You need to let the function return and get called again with a new parameter.

Comment: so what should I do? Sorry I am new to this